# find the rate of change of x with respect to θ when $θ = 45°$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry

- A ladder is placed $50$ meters from a wall at and angle $\theta$ with the horizontal the top of the ladder is $x$ meters above the ground.
- If the bottom of the ladder is pushed toward the wall, find the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $\theta$ when
  $\theta = 45^{\Large\circ}$.

Comment: What questions do you have about this problem?

Comment: $$x = r\sin(\theta) ~: ~r = 50\sqrt{2},$$ so $$\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \color{red}{\text{what ?}}$$

Comment: Alternative is $$x = 50\tan(\theta).$$

Comment: The question is not very clear.

Comment: Ladder questions have always pictures with them in calculus books.

Comment: The answer from @user2661923 is correct. At the final step, by using implicit differentiation, substitute $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, you will find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From trig figure directly

[image]

$$ \text{L is ladder length},~x = L\sin \theta~, \frac{dx}{d\theta} =L\cos \theta=50\cos 45^{\circ} \tag 1$$

And if you want the rate for any other $x,$ there is the circle relation

[image]

$$ x^2+ \left( \frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2 =L^2 \tag 2 $$

obtained by eliminating $\theta$ in equation 1)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can you share any article about this circle relation.

Comment: Directly we eliminate $\theta$ from $~x = L\sin \theta~, \dfrac{dx}{d\theta} =L\cos \theta$

Comment: @ zeeshan khan: I have added another answer reflecting a scaled up  situation when base is 50 meters. Hope it removes any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If the base is of $50$ meters length, then the figure should be scaled up by a magnification factor $\sqrt2.$

From trig figure directly

[image]

$$ \text{LL is ladder length} = 50\sqrt 2,~x = LL\sin \theta~, \frac{dx}{d\theta} =LL\cos \theta\tag 1$$

And if you want the rate for any other $x,$ there is the circle relation

$$ x^2+ \left( \frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2 =LL^2 \tag 2 $$

obtained by eliminating $\theta$ in equations 1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Narasimham did a nice job but I'll give another answer to this

$$x/50 =tan(θ) $$
$$x = 50 [tan(θ)]$$
$$dx/dθ = 50 sec^2(θ)$$
$$put θ= 45$$
$$dx/dθ= 50sec^2(45)$$
$$dx/dθ= 50(sqrt2)^2 = 50 (2) = 100$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @ Zeeshan khan: Is 50 m ladder length or horizontal distance to foot of ladder from origin?

Comment: @Narasimham No, its not the length of ladder. It's the horizontal distance from the wall. More specifically base of triangle.

Comment: @zeeshan khan: In your ladder problem what is it that remains constant and what does undergo a change? It should e clear.